# Sprite Movement Troubleshooting help in Unity?

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get an object to move every second in Unity, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm trying to make the game snake, and I'm starting off by centering the Sprite of the head, and starting it by moving it to the right every second, later adding player controls.
Any help with getting it to work?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Snake_Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector2 pos;
    private Vector2 moveDirection;
    private float moveTimer;
    private float timerSeconds;

    private void Startup()
    {
        pos = new Vector2(5, 5);
        timerSeconds = 1f;
        moveTimer = timerSeconds;
        moveDirection = new Vector2(1, 0);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        moveTimer += Time.deltaTime;

        if (moveTimer > timerSeconds)
        {
            pos += moveDirection;
            moveTimer -= timerSeconds;
        }

        transform.position = new Vector2(pos.x, pos.y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `Startup` is never called so all your values will keep their default values - in particular `pos = Vector2.zero` and `moveDirection = Vector2.zero` so your object will never move at all.

---

You probably rather wanted to call it `Start` in order to implement the Unity message [`MonoBehaviour.Start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) that is called automatically

> on the frame when a script is enabled just before any of the Update methods are called the first time.

```
public class Snake_Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    // These you adjust in the Inspector in Unity
    // Later changes to the values here will have no effect!
    [Tooltip("Time interval between steps in seconds")]
    [SerializeField] private float stepInterval = 1f;

    [Tooltip("Initial position")]
    private Vector2 startPos = new Vector2(5, 5);

    private Vector2 moveDirection;
    private float moveTimer;

    // What you wanted is probably the Unity message method Start
    // which is called when you app starts
    private void Start()
    {
        moveTimer = stepInterval;
        moveDirection = Vector2.right;

        transform.position = startPos;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        moveTimer += Time.deltaTime;

        if (moveTimer > stepInterval)
        {
            moveTimer -= stepInterval;

            // No need to store the pos, simply only assign a new value
            // to the position when needed
            transform.position += moveDirection;
        }
    }
}
```